# mysqli incorrect number of rows returned

Tags: php, mysqli, usercake

I'm writing a 'like' feature for my website and for the life of me, I just can't get this function working!

Assuming this is a simplified version my database structure:

> id --- post_id --- user_id
>
> 1  --- 1       ----------- 1
>
> 2  --- 2       ----------- 1

And this is the code I've written:

```
    public function userHasLikedPost($post_id,$user_id){
        $this->post_id_clean = sanitize($post_id);
        $this->user_id_clean = sanitize($user_id);

        global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT like_type FROM ".$db_table_prefix."post_likes WHERE user_id = ? AND post_id = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $this->post_id_clean, $this->user_id_clean);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();  

        $stmt->bind_result($like_type);

        $stmt->fetch();
        $result;

        if( $stmt->num_rows >0 ){
            $result = array("liked" => 1, "like_type" => $like_type);
        }else{
            $result = array("liked" => 0);
        }

        return print_r($stmt);

        $stmt->close();
    }
```

When I call userHasLikedPost(1,1) my code will return the **correct** number of rows

> mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows]
>   => **1** [param_count] => 2 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 5 ) 1

However, if I call userHasLikedPost(2,1) I will get the *incorrect* number of rows.

> mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows]
>   => **0** [param_count] => 2 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 5 ) 1

Why is this happening? Am I using mysqli correctly? The data exists in the database, and if I run the query manually in PHPMyAdmin I will get the correct output. I've spent like 2 hours trying to get this one function working... Thanks in advance for any replies :)

Comment: Does your sanitize function apply quotes to the string?  It is just that mysqli will also sanitize the values bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed my problem. My bindings were in the incorrect order :/ How embarrassing haha!

Solution:

Replace this line of code:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $this->post_id_clean, $this->user_id_clean);
```

With:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $this->user_id_clean, $this->post_id_clean);
```

Comment: Hi Joel, glad you got it fixed. Would you mind expanding this answer and include your updated code so that it's more useful to future vistors

Comment: I was just about to post that! No problem, we all do that ;)